# PHPstorm 7.1 opens "Authentication Required" dialog for SVN after every application restart

Tags: macos, svn, phpstorm

I have a problem - when working with svn on my projects, PHPstorm saves credentials only for one session, when I restart the app it asks for username and password again. Is there some way to force app save my credentials forever? When I work with Net Beans there is no such problem. SVN 1.8, mac os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's an answer from jetbrains support:

It's a known issue with old SVN and PhpStorm versions.

You can install 1.8 SVN client and configure PhpStorm to use it: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/subversion-1-8-and-intellij-idea-13/ .

Try to login from the command line 1.8 client to your repository and specify the password so that it's cached. PhpStorm should no longer ask for a password when working via the command line client.

You can also try 8.0 PhpStorm version.